# Ajax array won't populate on drop down select

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

As soon as selected value from `dropdown1` is changed, I need to populate the corresponding data for `dropdown1`'s selected value. The populated data must be appended to `dropdown2`.

I checked related answers and questions about this and tried almost every possible solution but I still can't get it to work.

**html**

```
<body>
<select id="dropdown1" class='form-control-static'>
    <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdown2" class='form-control-static'>
</select>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/externalJavascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

**externalJavascript**

```
$('select[name=dropdown1]').change(function (e) {
        var selected = $('select[name=dropdown1]').val() 
        alert(selected);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: { name: selected },
            url: 'dbaccess.php',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                var $select = $('#dropdown2');
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value.name + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

**dbaccess.php**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$name_id = getIdByName($name);

$names_arr = array();
$names_arr = getNamesByNameId($name_id);
//var_dump($names_arr);
echo json_encode($names_arr);
?>
```

The message **alert** box returns correct data as shown in SQL Editor
    `alert(data)` shows returned data from database as

```
[{"name":"My Name 1"},{"name":"My Name 2"},{"name":"My Name 3"}]
```

But it just won't append to the `dropdown2` select no matter what I do.
I don't see any problem with the `ajax`.

Any thoughts or ideas? I'll appreciate any help or suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any errors in the console? Does the code find the select element? Does the code go into the loop? console.log() is your friend. And not all the indexes have "name" in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole code is perfect just missing one line.

Just add **JSON.parse** function in ajax success call.

```
success: function(data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                .........
            }
```

Comment: You're a genius. I tried different solutions and examples online but none of them solved my problem. Your answer did solve my problem. Thanks.